# Secret hats are so secret those who earn them don't know why!

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign

So some hats are designated as "secret hats." Some of them are pretty guessable as to how you got them (if you happen to do so), but others are quite a mystery. Is there a way for people who are awarded secret hats to learn how they got the hat or what it means?

Comment: see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winterbash-2013

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the answer is that any secret hats that may or may not exist are secret by design, and that should said hats exist (which they may or may not), part of the fun is to try to guess why you might have received one.